# SSH connection to Raspberry Pi using 2 internet and 2 routers

Tags: networking, router, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have two internet connection and both of them have public static IPs. Both of this internet connections are connected to their own separate routers and these two routers are connected to each other from LAN to LAN. One of the router has DHCP disabled.
First router has gateway of **192.168.0.1** and second router has gateway of **192.168.0.2**.
First Router with gateway **192.168.0.1** has DHCP enabled and Raspberry Pi is connected to this first router via LAN cable and WiFi is disabled in Raspberry Pi.
In both of the router, I have done port forwarding for port 22 pointing to Raspberry Pi local IP.
The problem is that I am only able to connect to Raspberry Pi via SSH from First router's public IP from the internet. I am not able to connect from second router public IP even though both of them have port forwarding enabled for port 22 pointing to Raspberry Pi local IP address. My raspberry PI do not have an static IP configuration but I have done IP reservation on router so Raspberry Pi will always receive same IP address.
What I noticed is that this depends on what gateway Raspberry Pi is using. I ran the `route -n` on my Raspberry Pi and saw that it was pointing to First router's **192.168.0.1** gateway hence I was able to connect it from First router's public static IP. If I change this gateway to **192.168.0.2**, then I can connect from second router's public static IP but not from the first one.
What configuration change that I can do to make sure my Raspberry Pi can be connected from either of the public static IP via SSH from internet? I need this to make sure I will at least have one way to connect when one of the internet is down.

Comment: The only way to reach your RPI from your second ISP would be for that router to also assigned it an IP address.  There is hardware that will load balance multiple connections.  The solution would be to use a switch, you might be able to add the route for both routers, but I wouldn't know where to begin to do that.

Comment: use nftables: set `ct mark` for "original" (`input` hook) traffics from the "alternate" router (by matching with `ether saddr`, and set `meta mark` (for `ip rule` `fwmark` matching) for the "replying" (`output` hook) traffics. Then with a ip rule you can look up a different route table that uses the alternate router as the default gateway for *only* those replies.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `ct mark` in nftables:

```
table ip alt_gateway {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority mangle; policy accept;
                ether saddr YOUR_SECOND_ROUTER_MAC ct mark set 0x00616c74
        }

        chain output {
                type route hook output priority mangle; policy accept;
                ct mark 0x00616c74 meta mark set 0x00616c74
        }
}
```

`ether saddr YOUR_SECOND_ROUTER_MAC` matches traffics that were forwarded by your second router (i.e. those that have its MAC Address as the source L2 address). Technically the rule also covers traffics originated from the router itself, so you may want to *either* add `ip saddr != 192.168.0.2` before `ct mark set` *or* a direct route for `192.168.0.2` in the alternate route table below.

The mark `0x00616c74` is arbitary, and the `meta mark` to set can be different from the `ct mark` (on the other hand, you can also have something like `meta mark set ct mark`, which is practically  equivalent to the above).

The `meta mark` can then be matched against an `ip rule` (that looks up an alternate route table for `default` route, where you can have `192.168.0.2` as the nexthop / gateway) with `fwmark`:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.2 table 123
ip rule add iif lo fwmark 0x00616c74 lookup 123
```

`iif lo` means that the rule only applies on traffics originated from this host. It's sort of optional and is meant to correspond with the fact that the above table does not deal with traffics *forwarded* by this host anyway, that is, you'll need additional chain/rules if this host also serves as some kind of router / gateway and that this trick is also needed for traffics from / to the hosts that it serves.

The table number `123` is also arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you @Tom Yan for detailed answer. Let me try this and check.